# Единое дисковое пространство

Tags: linux, файлы

Можно ли каким-либо чудом на нескольких серверах сделать единое дисковое пространство?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Распределенная файловая система GFS](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/development/73673/)

> GFS является наиболее, наверное,
> известной распределенной файловой
> системой. Надежное масштабируемое
> хранение данных крайне необходимо для
> любого приложения, работающего с таким
> большим массивом данных, как все
> документы в интернете. GFS является
> основной платформой хранения
> информации в Google. GFS — большая
> распределенная файловая система,
> способная хранить и обрабатывать
> огромные объемы информации.

Comment: GFS - попробовал, понравилось :)) Спасибо, то что нужно ))) !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Для совместного доступа к файлам NFS, Samba, ... вообще их много.

Если монтировать файловые системы (диски) не одновременно (по очереди), то таких устройств хранения тоже полно. Вы можете управлять распределением дисковой памяти на них. Подключаются они обычно по FibreChannel или i-SCSI (раньше в основном по SCSI (знатоки из IBM наверняка поправят)).

Можно работать с диском, подключенным к двум (SCSI) или большему (FibreChannel для других (например InfiniBand) не пробовал) числу серверов без файловой системы (по raw device), но синхронизацию надо обеспечивать самому. Это я делал в *nix (для Windows не знаю).

Comment: Интересует именно LINUX.
Можно ли у Вас попросить ссылочи полезные ? Если Вы подобное уже делали, думаю, Вы сможете подсказать дорожку на путь истинный :)

P.S. Хочу добиться следующего:

Например, копируя в папку /var/cache/ какой-нибудь файл, я не знал на какой сервер он попадет, но всегда мог обратиться к ниму по адресу /var/cache/myfile.co

Comment: Наверное я Ваш вопрос не так понял. 

Про /var/cache/

Вы просто со всех машин монтируете по NFS одну и ту же файловую систему определенного сервера в /var/cache (на машинах, которые монтируют она пустая) и все машины по локальному имени /var/cache/myfile.co видят один и тот же файл, который располагается на этом сервере (в той файловой системе, которую он экспортирует).

Откровенно говоря, я Ваш P.S. так и не понял.

P.S. ссылочек у меня нет, посмотрите NFS в Google.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря сколько серверов и какие требования к надежности. На википедии есть [список файловых систем](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_файловых_систем). Просто можно смотреть как в сторону просто распределенных файловых систем (например NFS), так и в сторону распределенных параллельных систем с защитой от сбоев